# Can we use one ALB with AWS ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I am having a bunch of micro services running in AWS ECS fargate with ALB and Route53.Each micro service has an ALB with Route53.

Is there any kind of possibility where I can use only one ALB for all the microservices and route to their respective Route53 paths??

Here, I am not using EKS. Using AWS ECS Fargate.

Comment: Yes, you can have different target groups for each service.

Comment: Can you explain Please @Marcin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To server multiple Fargate services from a single ALB, you need to create **different target groups (TGs)** for them. So, each service will have its own TG, and ALB will forward traffic to respective TGs based on some listener rules.

Since you have Route53, a common choice is to create sub-domains, e.g.: `service1.example.com` and `service2.example.com`. You associate them as simple Alias A records with the same ALB.

On the ALB you will have **single listener** (e.g. HTTP 80), with **different rules**. For example:

1. Rule one will be based on `Host header` equal to `service1.example.com`, with `Action` of `Forward` to TG1.
2. Rule two will be based on `Host header` equal to `service2.example.com`, with `Action` of `Forward` to TG2.
3. Some default rule compulsory (or use 2 as default rule).

And that's it. Any request from the internet directed to `service1.example.com` will go to your TG1 which is Fragete service1. Same for requests to `service2.example.com`.

Comment: Any extra charges for adding different rules for a ALB? @Marcin

Comment: @Megha ALB pricing includes [rules](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/). But whatever it is, it should be much cheaper then running separate ALB's for each service.

Comment: I have a doubt. With using one ALB to all the services, the urls that are linked to the LB will face any slowness while using??

Comment: @Megha ALB scales with load. This is one of key reasons why people use manged load balancers from AWS - it can handle large traffic if needed.

Comment: Ok. In case of  getting very slow often. Can we increase the task CPU and memory utilization with increase in desired count as well??

Comment: ALB is manged service, you can't change its CPU or memory. But ECS tasks and services are up to you, thus you can modify them as needed.

Comment: Yes, by modifying the ECS tasks CPU and memory, the slowness issue will be solved? This is my doubt.

Comment: @Megha I'm not sure what do you mean. Maybe it would be good to make a new question, with the relevant details. If your tasks are slow there could be a lot of reasons, ranging from bugs in your application to insufficient cpu and/or ram. Thus its difficult to speculate on this.